# Read invalid json in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with decoding json.
Here is the screen of the json where Google Chrome and Java recognized it.

Chrome: https://ibb.co/gZ33Qa

Android Studio: https://ibb.co/kTXV5a

I can not decode it in PHP via json_decode(), error number 4 is a syntax error.
How can you fix this json?

json himself

```html
{"rs":[["addChd",["sFCF6",[
['zul.wgt.Div','sFCFb',{sclass:'transparent table contentHolder',prolog:'\n    '},[
['zk.Native','sFCFc',{prolog:'\n        
<h1>Управляющая компания',epilog:'</h1>'},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFd',{prolog:'\n
<table>\n            ',epilog:'\n        </table>'},[
['zk.Native','sFCFe',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td colspan="2">\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFf',{id:'nameLabel',sclass:'value',style:'font-weight: bold',value:'Общество с ограниченной ответственностью Управляющая компания "Якутск"'},[]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFg',{prolog:'\n            '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFh',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td colspan="2">\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFi',{id:'addressLabel',sclass:'value',multiline:true,value:'РС (Я), г.Якутск, ул.Орджоникидзе, д.38'},[]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFj',{prolog:'\n            '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFk',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td>Телефоны:</td>\n
    <td>\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFl',{id:'phoneLabel',sclass:'value',value:'8(4112) 40-56-41'},[]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFm',{prolog:'\n            '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFn',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td>Директор:</td>\n
    <td>\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFo',{id:'directorLabel',sclass:'value',value:'Молонов Алексей Владимирович тел.: 89142946345'},[]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFp',{prolog:'\n            '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFq',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td>Бухгалтер:</td>\n
    <td>\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFr',{id:'accounterLabel',sclass:'value',value:'Антипина Русалина Николаевна тел.: 89142946345'},[]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFs',{prolog:'\n            '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFt',{prolog:'
<tr>\n                
    <td>Эл. адрес:</td>\n
    <td>\n                    ',epilog:'\n                </td>\n
</tr>'},[
['zul.wgt.Label','sFCFu',{id:'emailLabel',sclass:'value',value:'kk_centr_2013@mail.ru'},[]]]]]],
['zk.Native','sFCFv',{prolog:'\n
<br/>'},[]],
['zul.box.Vlayout','sFCFw',{id:'noteHolder',prolog:'\n        '},[]],
['zk.Native','sFCFx',{prolog:'\n
<br/>'},[]]]]]]],["script",["jq('.contentHolder').hide().fadeIn(500); select_menu_item('organization');"]]],"rid":1}
```

Comment: String values must be in double-quotes, and keys (`sclass`, `prolog`...) must also be in double-quotes. The solution is simple: fix whatever is generating this not-JSON.

Comment: could you paste some of the php code you use to achieve the decoding? btw it might fail due to the double quotes `<td colspan="2">`, try to not include double quotes at all, php json encoder might be more strict than the Chrome one.

Comment: How do you create this JSON String? Thats where the error is!

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to find where the error is

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is right. JSON is very strict about the use of double quotes. _All_ keys must be quoted, and _all_ keys and other strings must be in double quotes. Google is not a good example to follow, and if it interprets JSON loosely, that doesn’t help. You might begin by replacing all your single quotes with double quotes, and finding all the keys and double quoting them too. BTW do you mean Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @Karlos php code https://ibb.co/fiXi8v

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is from api

Comment: @Manngo php code

Comment: Why are you using `curl_multi_getcontents()` when you are not initializing a `curl_multi` session??

Comment: @МичилХабаров OK, it’s coming from somebody else’s API. I had a similar problem with a Google API, long gone. You can try this: somewhere between lines 93 & 95 fix up your `$result` string as I suggested — that is, use a string replace to change `'` to `"` and use `preg_replace` to wrap bare keys inside double quotes. I haven’t test this for a long time, for for the latter, you could try: `$pattern='/\b([^"].*?[^"])\b:(.*?[,}])/'; $json=preg_replace($pattern,'"\1":\2',$json);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with what the API is delivering. I have had a similar problem in the past with a Google API delivering incorrect JSON.

You could try the following:

Replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
$result=str_replace($test,'\'','"');
```

Use `preg_replace` to wrap keys in double quotes:

```
$pattern='/\b([^"].*?[^"])\b:(.*?[,}])/';
$result=preg_replace($pattern,'"\1":\2',$result);
```

That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code you sent, and just in order to make it work, you could:

```
try {
    $decrypted = json_decode($result);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $sane = str_replace('="', '=\"', $result);
    $healthy = str_replace('">', '\">', $sane);
    $decrypted = json_decode($healthy);
}
```

This is a hack. I would recommend for our case, that is:

- (non convenient) storing **html code** as **json strings**
- (issue) html has lots of character `"`
- (issue) you are using php json encoder which is a **strict encoder**

A solution could be to parse every single object with a prolog key in your json string:

1. Find first prolog tag start position (`pos`) with [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) php methods.
2. Find the string start position after prolog (`pos`), right after the following `:'`
   let's call it `stringstart`
3. Find the end of that string by finding the closest `'},` or `'}` after `stringstart`. This will be your `stringend`.
4. Replace all occurrences of the character `"` by the character `'` between `stringstart` and `stringend` positions in your json string.
5. find next prolog.

**NOTE**
In order to save time, you could try to persist the stuff from your remote response by parsing it differently, using a ODM on a simple local db, etc.

I hope it is useful.